# FormPanel "addFormPanel" method undefined

Tags: gwt

There are lots of sample for this kind of code in the web:

```
    FormPanel form = FormPanel.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("login"), true); 
    form.setAction("javascript:;");
    form.addFormPanel(new FormPanel() { 
             public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) { 
              } 
              public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) { 
              } 
           });
```

However, the `addFormPanel` method is undefined.

I am using GWT 2.1.0 BTW

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are lots of sample for this kind of code in the web:

Where have you seen such examples?

I think,there was not such method in FormPanel(in earlier([1.6](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html), [2.1](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html)  or even in [2.3](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html)) 
If you want to add `onSubmit` and/or `onSubmitComplete`  handlers just do the same which is given in documentations:

```
// Add an event handler to the form.
    form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
      public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can take
        // this opportunity to perform validation.
        if (tb.getText().length() == 0) {
          Window.alert("The text box must not be empty");
          event.cancel();
        }
      }
    });
    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
      public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
        // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
        // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
        // further explanation).
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this approach already. The code I copied was from the forum so it could have been that the code was the problem